# Invoke AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthCheck from code without a call to HTTP endpoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-service-fabric, health-monitoring

I have added the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks` on a collection of Service Fabric services, some of which have a HTTP ServiceEndpoints and some do not.

For the ones which do not have a service endpoint, if I wanted to add some implementations of `IHealthCheck` and add them to the `ServiceCollection` in `StartUp` as follows:

```
services
  .AddHealthChecks()
   .AddCheck<DatabaseHealthCheck>("Database")
   .AddCheck<Api1HealthCheck>("Dependency API 1")
   .AddCheck<Api2HealthCheck>("Dependency API 2");
```

is there a way of invoking those health checks without calling a HTTP endpoint on the service itself?

These particular services have a while loop like this in the `RunAsync` method currently to output a heartbeat to the logs:

```
public async Task RunAsync(string appInstanceDesc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        long iterations = 0;
        var sleepTimeSpan = _config.PollingInterval.GetTimeSpan();

        while (true)
        {
            if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Cancellation requested - shutting down");
                break;
            }

            _logger?.LogDebug($"CR Heartbeat log iteration 
                                   {++iterations}{appInstanceDesc}");

            Thread.Sleep(sleepTimeSpan);
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to invoke the `HealthCheck` classes from within that loop so that the results of which can be output to the logs?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you added built-in health check framework:

`services.AddHealthChecks()`

If you do:

`.. appBuilder.ApplicationServices.GetService<HealthCheckService>();`

or

`.. serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<HealthCheckService>();`

in order to manually execute the `CheckHealthAsync` and get a `HealthReport` back that contains the statuses:

`HealthReport healthReport = await healthCheckService.CheckHealthAsync();`

Make sure that you are using the right `HealthCheckService` because it exists at two places, in:

`using Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks;`

and in:

`using Microsoft.Extensions.HealthChecks;`

In my case, I had to use the one from `Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this:

1. Get a `HealthCheckService` instance from the container (`IServiceProvider`).
2. Pass it to your service if needed
3. Call `healthCheckService.CheckHealthAsync` to get the health status.
4. (bonus) Use `await Task.Delay(sleepTimeSpan)` instead of `Thread.Sleep`

This idea is based on the middleware code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Middleware/HealthChecks/src/HealthCheckMiddleware.cs).